# Refresh view after Pop with react-native-router-flux

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have big problem with my first React Native app. I've spend few hours today to find the solution but unfortunately nothing helps me.

I have two views:

```
<Router>
    <Stack>
      <Scene key="objectsList"
         component={ ObjectsList } title="Objects"
         onRight={() => Actions.addObject()} rightTitle="Add object" />
      <Scene key="addObject" component={ AddObject } title="Add" />
    </Stack>
</Router>
```

First view is a `FlatList` that is displaying data loaded from `AsyncStorage`. User can add new object by pressing the right button **Add object** on the navigation bar. `AddObject` Scene will be present on the screen. There is another `FlatList` with some options. User can tap on the cell and then the data is save to the `AsyncStorage` and after that I call `Actions.pop();` function.

The view is gone but I couldn't refresh first screen **Objects** to reload data and display new value. I've tried a lot solutions from git, stackoverflow and other forums. Nothing works for me.

I am using `react-native-router-flux` for routing.

I will be glad for help or example code because I am stuck on this problem and it block my project.

P.S. I want to refresh view, send new props or do something that will not reload whole Component. There is a map on it and if I am reloading whole View it is loading from the beginning. I want only to inform that there is some change and run some function to refresh it.

**EDIT:**

After implemented the solution proposed by **Phyo** unfortunately I couldn't refresh the data in proper way. When user choose something on AddObject scene he comes back to first view but nothing happened. The change is implemented after user open AddObject scene second time. The function from props is running only when scene 2 is appear again.

My second attempt looks like that:

**ObjectsList**

```
  state = { selectedObject: "" }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadSelectedObject();
  }

  refreshState() {
    this.loadSelectedObject();
  }

  loadSelectedObject() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('ObjectKey', (err, object) => {
      if (object) {
        this.setState({ selectedObject: object })
      }
    });
  }

render() {
  return(
    <Button onPress={() => Actions.addObject({onBack: refreshState()})}>
  );
}
```

**Add Object**

```
onPressItem = (object) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('ObjectKey', object, () => {
      this.props.onBack;
      Actions.pop();
    });
  };

  render() {
     return (
       <FlatList
            data={this.state.objects}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item}
            key={this.state.numColumns}
            numColumns={this.state.numColumns}
            renderItem={(data) =>
              <LineCell onPressItem={this.onPressItem} object={String(data.item.object)} />
     );
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with friend's help. The code:

**ObjectsList**

```
  state = { selectedObject: "" }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadSelectedObject();
  }

  refreshState() {
    this.loadSelectedObject();
  }

  loadSelectedObject() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('ObjectKey', (err, object) => {
      if (object) {
        this.setState({ selectedObject: object })
      }
    });
  }

render() {
  return(
    <Button onPress={() => Actions.addObject()}>
  );
}
```

**Add Object**

```
onPressItem = (object) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('ObjectKey', object, () => {
      Actions.pop();
      Actions.refs.objectsList.refreshState(); //Solution
    });
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

- On your first view, create a function e.g., `refreshFirstView()` and pass that function to the second view.
- On your second view, call that function `this.props.refreshFristView()` before you called `Actions.pop()`
- In your `refreshFirstView()` on the first view, simply call all the function you called to retrieve from `AsyncStorage`.

## First View

```
componentDidMount(){
  retrieveAsynStorageItems()
  doSomeOtherLikeFilteringOrSorting()
}

refreshFirstView(){
  retrieveAsynStorageItems()//by calling this func again you will get newly saved item
  doSomeOtherLikeFilteringOrSorting()
}
```

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Phyo unfortunately it doesn't work. Please check my edited question post for more details.